# Installing Chamilo LMS - Remote server or file not found

Tags: php, apache, module

After installing Chamilo 1.9 I get a:

```
Remote server or file not found
```

On domain.com/chamilo/index.php

When I open domain.com/chamilo/version.php (which is just ) it shows 5.3.15, where Chamilo requires 5.3.X.

I thought it was my .htaccess file but it does not contain anything obtrusive:

```
# Use PHP 5.3
 AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
 # Check that your Apache virtualhost have this settings:

#<Directory "/var/www/chamilo-classic">
#  AllowOverride All
#  Order allow,deny
#  Allow from all
#</Directory>

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^certificates/$ certificates/index.php?id=%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?$1 [L]

# This will transform
# http://my.chamilo.net/certificates/?id=123     to  http://my.chamilo.net/    certificates/index.php?id=123 
# http://my.chamilo.net/juliomontoya        to       http://    my.chamilo.net/user.php?juliomontoya
```

But I see that my hosting provider turned off php errors and instead logs it:

```
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: magickwand: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sqlite.so: undefined symbol: third_arg_force_ref in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2012 19:59:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead' in /home/domain/chamilo/main/inc/lib/symfony/Twig/Extension/Core.php:420
Stack trace:
#0 /home/domain/chamilo/main/inc/lib/symfony/Twig/Extension/Core.php(420): DateTime->__construct('now')
#1 /home/domain/chamilo/main/inc/lib/symfony/Twig/Extension/Core.php(390): twig_date_converter(Object(Twig_Environment), 'now', NULL)
#2 /home/domain/chamilo/archive/twig/89/5c/c0f0daf45dd618c8ea2e2bbaf856.php(121): twig_date_format_filter(Object(Twig_Environment), 'now', 'Y')
#3 /home/domain/chamilo/main/inc/lib/symfony/Twig/Template.php(278): __TwigTemplate_8 in /home/domain/chamilo/main/inc/lib/symfony/Twig/Template.php on line 282
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The only error you have in your logs, there, is (if you scroll to the right) that your date.timezone parameter is not set in php.ini (I think you can set it in .htaccess with php_flag as well).
If you're in Berlin, for example, you would set:

`php_flag date.timezone Europe/Berlin`

in your .htaccess (or just look for "timezone" in your php.ini).

If you want to include the timezone setting command date_default_timezone_set() provided below, put it inside main/inc/global.inc.php, this is loaded by all scripts in Chamilo. At the very beginning of the file, it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the code to set the time zone of the application

date_default_timezone_set ('America / Sao_Paulo');

Answer (score 0):

Alright, apparently setting the PHP extension (5.3) in the htaccess file does not use the updates PHP modules. So you need to have full 5.3 support rather than this hacky htaccess include